# Can the content of the context be transmitted in grpc?

Tags: go, grpc

I have defined a client and server. They all have a ctx(context) as parameter,client and server communicate by grpc.

```
type Client interface {
    GetFileVersion(ctx context.Context, in *Req) (*Resp, error)
}

type client struct {
    cc *grpc.ClientConn
}

func (c *client) GetFileVersion(ctx context.Context, in *Req) (*Resp, error) {
    out := new(Resp)
    err := grpc.Invoke(ctx, "/testpb/GetFileVersion", in, out, c.cc, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}



type Server interface {
    GetFileVersion(context.Context, *Req) (*Resp, error)
}
```

If I set value in ctx in the implement of GetFileVersion in client,can I get this value in server?

```
ctx = context.WithValue(parent, "test", 123)
```

Comment: That functionality does not exist in the context library. If you have values in your context that need to be transmitted, this must be done manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`context` is a general purpose registry for global **request** variables. It is not supposed to escape the request scope. Consider doing this another way.